# How can I dynamically inject a stylesheet in React without the website flickering/reloading?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, stylesheet, next.js

I have a React application (next.js) that receives a stylesheet from a GET request and then appends it to the webpage.

When I load in the stylesheet the elements that are affected by that stylesheet rerender even if they are not changed. For example the stylesheet includes global styling to h1 tags, however the styling does not differ from the current styling yet it still re-renders.

Is there a way I can prevent this re-render/flicker/reload so that I can provide the user a seamless browsing experience?

Comment: Loading a stylesheet should not cause the page to rerender. Maybe there's another issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **[reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect)**. 
It supports memoization and I think this is what you are looking for.

React uses shallow compare to compare objects. When an app downloads new data from server, it receives a new object with styles data. React compares it with current props. Even if this object has the same data, for React it is going to be a new a object, so it decides to re-render the component.

Using reselect we are saving last object, that we received before and compare it with the new one. If the new object has exactly the same structure, reselect will send the old object (memoized object) to the component. This way the component will receive the same object and it will not be re-rendered.

Usually reselect is used with Redux, but according their FAQ it can be used independently:

> **Q: Can I use Reselect without Redux?**   A: Yes. Reselect has no dependencies on any other package, so although it was designed to be
>   used with Redux it can be used independently. It is currently being
>   used successfully in traditional Flux apps

Comment: React uses shallow compare to compare objects. When app downloads new data from server, it recieves new object with styles data. React compare it with current props. Even if this object has same data, for react it is going to be a new object, so it decides to rerender the component.
Using reselect we are saving last object, that we've recieved before and compare it with the new one. If it has totally same structure, reselect send old object (memoized object) to the component. This way component receiving same object and it will not be rerendered.

Comment: You're assuming the OP uses redux at all.

Comment: According to their FAQ:
Q: Can I use Reselect without Redux?
A: Yes. Reselect has no dependencies on any other package, so although it was designed to be used with Redux it can be used independently. It is currently being used successfully in traditional Flux apps.